# Javascript code adding empty records to mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a short problem. 
Here is my form layout:

```
    <form class="form-inline" action="javascript:addRecord();" method="GET">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label for="konu">Konu:</label> 
                <input class="form-control " type="text" name="konu" required="required" placeholder="Bir konu yazın"/>
            </div>                                                                          
        </div>                                                        
    </div>  
    <br>                          
    <div class="form-group col-lg-5 ">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Kaydet</button>  
    </div>                            
</form>

    <div id="add-record-div" class="alert alert-success" hidden="hidden">
         <strong>RECORD INSERTED</strong>    
    </div>
```

And my javascript code:

```
function addRecord() 
{                   
    $.post('add.php', function(data) 
    {    
        trHTML += 
        '<tr><td>' + value.id + 
        '</td><td>' + value.konu + 
        '</td><td>' + value.aciklama + 
        '</td><td>' + value.giris_tarih + 
        '</td><td>' + value.degistirilme_tarih + 
        '</td><td>' + value.ad_soyad + 
        '</td><td>' + value.email + 
        '</td></tr>';     
    });

    getLastRecord();       
    $('#add-record-div').show('slow').delay('1000'); 
    $('#add-record-div').hide('slow');                                                  
}
```

Databse insert looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDiiC.jpg
 My problem is this function adds only empty rows to mysql. '`giris_tarih`' and `'degistirilme_tarih'` are date values. Those are being added correctly but other columns are always empty. There is no problem with `add.php` page. If I only write: `form class="form-inline"` `action="add.php"` it works perfectly. But I couldn't get it worked with javascript function.

Comment: I need to see a little bit further from your code.

Comment: Please show us what are the values for id, konu, aciklama, etc and how you insert them in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched actions in your markup and script, and also your data is pointing to value which is not part of the object returned from your `add.php` (you set your ajax response to the variable `data`, therefore you must use `data.propName...`). I also corrected your table formatting a bit and used jQuery like the rest of your module.

```
function addRecord() 
{                   
    $.get('add.php', function(data) 
    {    


        $('#your-table').append('<tr>' + data.id + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + data.konu + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + data.aciklama + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + data.giris_tarih + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + data.degistirilme_tarih + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + data.ad_soyad +  '</td>'
        + '<td>' + data.email + '</td>'
        + '</tr>');

    getLastRecord();       
    $('#add-record-div').show('slow').delay('1000'); 
    $('#add-record-div').hide('slow');                                                  
}
```

Comment: You must be sure your prop names being called from this script here are in alignment with the ones in your backend otherwise this will still give you empty data in your db because the values do not resolve t anything being sent. I would console.log(data) so you can see what your add.php is sending you after that ajax call.